# Explicitly labeling end points in matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the matplotlib graph above, the x-axis ranges from 850 - 2015. I would like them to be explicitly labeled. Is there a way to force matplotlib to do that?

I am doing this: `ax.set_xlim([min(xvar), max(xvar)])`, here xvar is the x-axis array ranging from 850 - 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels` to set the location and content of labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
a.set_xlim(1,10.5)
a.set_xticks([0, 5, 10, 10.5])
a.set_xticklabels([0, 5, 10, 10.5])
```

[image]